# Coordinates of exterior derivative of dual basis of local frame for the tangent bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, lie-derivative

Let $M$ be an $n$-manifold. Let $E_1, E_2,\dots, E_n : U\subset M \to TM $ be a local frame for $TM$ with associated local dual frame $\epsilon^1, \epsilon^2,\dots, \epsilon^n : U\subset M \to T^*M $.

Suppose that $[E_i, E_j] = \sum_{k=1}^n c_{ij}^k E_k$ the exercise asks to   show that
$d \epsilon^k = - \sum_{i,j} c_{i j}^k\  \epsilon^i \wedge \epsilon^j = \sum_{i<j} (c_{j i}^k - c_{i j}^k) \ \epsilon^i \wedge \epsilon^j $.

I've tried to solve it in the following way:
$d \epsilon^k (E_i, E_j) = E_i (\epsilon^k(E_j)) -  E_j (\epsilon^k(E_i)) - \epsilon^k([E_i, E_j])$ since   $E_i (\epsilon^k(E_j)) = 0$ for any $i,j,k$
I've obtained that $d \epsilon^k (E_i, E_j) =  - \epsilon^k([E_i, E_j]) = -c_{i j}^k$, thus $d \epsilon^k =  \sum_{i<j} -c_{i j}^k\  \epsilon^i \wedge \epsilon^j $.

Where is the mistake? It is possible that the exercise is not correct? How can it be corrected?.

Comment: Maybe it is missing a factor $2$, but I am insecure. Try inverting the roles of $i$ and $j$ in you formula and summing up.

Comment: First of all, the fact that Lie bracket is anticommutative tells you that $c^k_{ij} = -c^k_{ji}$. The answer *should* be $\sum_{i<j} -c^k_{ij} \epsilon^i\wedge\epsilon^j=-\frac12\sum_{i,j} c^k_{ij}\epsilon^i\wedge\epsilon^j$ (assuming you have the definition of wedge product with $\epsilon^1\wedge\epsilon^2(E_1,E_2) = 1$ and not $1/2$).